# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, http-headers

So I saw this great post [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client) , but still do not understand, what is wrong with my Headers section, because when I changed it from my `commented out` wrong type into two separated sections:
   `app.use(doesNotModifyBody);`
    `app.use(doesModifyBody);`  (like in answer above) it does not work normally.

And for now, instead of receiving the right database answer, I always resive the string from the `app.use(doesModifyBody);` - `res.write("<p>Hello World</p>");`.

So the question, how to solve the error with the Headers in the question title and make right database answer receving, instead of `res.write("<p>Hello World</p>");` P.S. deleting the `res.write("<p>Hello World</p>");` is does not solve the problem.

My server code:

```
'use strict'
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const EmployersSchemaDB = require('./SchemaDB/EmployersSchemaDB');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://myDB');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
//     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
//     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
//     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
//     res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
//     next();
// }); I change this on:

let doesNotModifyBody = (req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    next();
  }; // this 
let doesModifyBody = (req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    res.write("<p>Hello World</p>");
    res.end();
  }; // and this

app.use(doesNotModifyBody);
app.use(doesModifyBody);

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: 'Server is Initialized!'});
});

router.route('/employers')
    .get((req, res) => {
        EmployersSchemaDB.find((err, employers) => {
            if (err) { res.send(err) }

            res.json(employers);
        });
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
        let employer = new EmployersSchemaDB();

        employer.first_name = req.body.first_name;
        employer.last_name = req.body.last_name;
        employer.birth_date = req.body.birth_date;
        employer.salary = req.body.salary;

        employer.save((err) => {
            if (err) { res.send(err) }

            res.json({ message: 'Comment successfully added!', employer });
            console.log('---===--- \n Employer added: \n', employer + '\n ---===---');
        });  
    });

router.route('/employers/:employer_id')
    .get((req, res) => {
        EmployersSchemaDB.findById(req.params.employer_id, (err, employer) => {
            if (err) { res.send(err) }

            res.json({ message: 'Employer has been getted', employer: employer });
        });
    })
    .put((req, res) => {
        EmployersSchemaDB.findById(req.params.employer_id, (err, employer) => {
            if (err) { res.send(err) }

            (req.body.id) ? employer.id = req.body.id : null;
            (req.body.first_name) ? employer.first_name = req.body.first_name : null;
            (req.body.last_name) ? employer.last_name = req.body.last_name : null;
            (req.body.birth_date) ? employer.birth_date = req.body.birth_date : null;
            (req.body.salary) ? employer.salary = req.body.salary : null;

            employer.save((err) => {
                if (err) { res.send(err) }

                res.json({ message: 'Employer has been updated', employer: employer  });
            });
        });
    })
    .delete((req, res) => {
        EmployersSchemaDB.remove({ _id: req.params.employer_id }, (err, employer) => {
            if (err) { res.send(err) }

            res.json({ message: 'Comment has been deleted' })
        })
    });

app.use('/', router);

const port = process.env.API_PORT || 3016;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Th issue is that you are calling

```
res.write("<p>Hello World</p>");
res.end();
```

Which sends the response back to the client. Once you do this you cannot send any further data. You try to do that by calling `res.json()` in your middleware, which is why you want get the error that you get;

Remove BOTH the `res.end` and `res.write` lines and it should work.

Comment: No, it does not work. You did not read my question fully:  **P.S. deleting the res.write("<p>Hello World</p>"); is does not solve the problem.**

Comment: I did read your question. U spoke about removing `res.write`. U also need to remove `res.end`